# Print in Solana Playground

Tags: anchor, anchor-test, solana-program-test, anchor-accounts

I want to debug my program in Solana Playground. I am using the print function to get logs. The containing function is running but not producing any logs. Attaching a screenshot below.[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try `msg!("asdf");` or `msg!("some var: {:?}", some_var)` to print a variable to the logs.

Comment: Additionally to see the logs in Playground, go to settings (gear in bottom left) and turn on "Show transaction details"